# A malicious folder is created automatically?

Tags: malware

After I ran a third party game and uninstalled it, my antivirus is showing this message repeatedly every 7-8 seconds.

[image]

When I run the antivirus it shows the malware detected and removed, but again the problem persists, the message is displayed. I found the folder in "C: drive" when I tried to delete the folder myself, it is created automatically. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, my PC and antivirus are fully updated.

Comment: What folder are you referring to?  The message is telling you that your antivirus is preventing you from accessing a malicious URL.

Comment: @ mark :I read the message and as it indicated the name 'opencandy',i searched that folder name in my C: drive and found and tried to delete it. but the folder is like ' nacromancied' ,it regenerates

Comment: @RK The message in the image says nothing about a folder. That's a website URL.

Answer (score 2):

The file it is trying to download is not exactly malware; it is a potentially unwanted program (PUP) (probably *spyware*). See [here](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/caabf372bec945b0760ac98b6428da819bfba6fd3f48ab2271bccaa8f777aeb4/analysis/) for details.

Apparently the game you downloaded was either downloaded by a downloader, or packaged into an installer, that relied on [OpenCandy](http://opencandy.com/faqs/).

From their site:

```
What is OpenCandy?

OpenCandy is a service that helps app developers earn money and keep their apps free-of-charge for you, the user. Developers earn money by recommending other select, free apps during the download and install process of their free app. We guarantee that all app recommendations are optional and you may choose to accept, decline, or uninstall any app at any time. As it takes an enormous amount of time, effort and investment to create apps, we are focused on helping these developers keep their apps free (and their lights on) while maintaining the highest quality user experience.
```

**Usually** you *should* get:

- a checkbox in the install process allowing you to opt-out and *not* install OpenCandy on your computer;
- an entry in the Control Panel > Installed Applications > Uninstall list allowing you to remove OpenCandy *after* you have installed it;
- OpenCandy entrypoints and hooks that are **not** hard to hunt down and kill.

Since it's too late for option #1, see whether condition #2 holds. Unless your game's developer was feeling particularly unscrupulous, you should be able to find an entry for either OpenCandy or Advertising which you'll be able to remove.

**IMPORTANT**: be aware that some tools claiming to remove OpenCandy or listing it among the spyware they remove **are malware in their own right**.

[This tool](http://download.spywareremove.com/spyhunter-free-download/spywareremove.com/SpyHunter-Installer.exe) (others exist) claims to be able to remove OpenCandy, and at this moment, [VirusTotal gives it a clean bill of health](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/a373e89e4368844af91152e9a6e477aee1a7a507c291c5b6bd739f937f0445e5/analysis/). (Their site *is* listed by ESET Smart Security, updated not five minutes ago, as "unsafe" - I have notified ESET).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the game was not a cracked version.
The cracked games sometimes have malicious files. The cracker of the game sometimes adds some malicious files so that these files can help the cracker to make some money by advertising or downloading files. Any how it is a better idea to rescan your machine completely. If nothing found then try scanning with a different antivirus product. For eg: [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/)

Also it seems that some malicious file on your machine is trying to connect to that particular URL and your antivirus is blocking it, because the URL seems to download an `.EXE` file.

If antivirus don't find any malicious file, then you might need to remove it manually.
Some steps you could take are:

1. Open up the task manager and see if can find any suspicious process
2. Find the file executing that process
3. Kill that process
4. Then delete that malicious file
5. Try removing any suspicious registry entries
6. Check the [startup menu entries](http://www.howtogeek.com/74523/how-to-disable-startup-programs-in-windows/?PageSpeed=noscript) and remove any suspicious entries, sometimes the malicious files starts every time during the bootup.
7. As you installed some game, so there is usually a folder where everything gets installed, try removing/deleting that forlder. [Helpful link](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/force-windows-delete-file/)

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: here is my process list i dont think there is any malicious process visible,  http://prntscr.com/7gfnuk

Comment: I don't see any suspicious process in the list. Trying using tasklist command in windows to get all the processes. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491010.aspx
Did you try scanning ur machine with malwarebytes or any other antivirus?

Comment: well i used malware bytes and the problem was removed . thanks.